# iPhone XR iOS 17.3 unable to summon “Stolen Device Protection” menu

Tags: iphone, security, ios

An iPhone XR is outfitted with iOS 17.3. “Settings > Face ID” returns:

[image]

I did could not find the security feature and did not turn it on.   When I tap my AppleID at the very to of Settings, it does nothing.

[*The Wall Street Journal*](https://www.wsj.com/tech/personal-tech/iphone-stolen-device-protection-ios-update-bbe68a11) indicates:

> “You must have two-factor authentication and Find My enabled for your Apple ID account to use Stolen Device Protection.”

My MacBooks’s "Find My" app is able to communicate with the iPhone.

*The Wall Street Journal*'s example indicates:

[image]

#### What must be done to access the menu as shown in the WSJ example?

Answer (score 4):

Apple support is almost always the best resource when a release feature is stuck since they have all the cards (server side data, notes from the engineers, and latest reports of issues whether it’s a trickle or a flood of user feedback).

That being said, if I had to troubleshoot this without contacting Apple, the first thing is I would turn off FaceID on my device and then power it off.

Next thing would be to review my Apple ID from an iPad or computer on the web so that it meets the three other requirements: significant locations enabled, Find My enabled and two factor security on your AppleID.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212510 (Stolen Device Protection)
- https://support.apple.com/102660 (Two Factor Auth)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102648 (Set up Find My)
- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/delete-significant-locations-iph32b15b22f/ios (Significant Locations)

I would ensure two factor was set before turning on the phone and checking. Next when the phone is on, check in on "significant location" to be sure that's working. Next, review Find My for that phone. Lastly, enable Face ID and re-check.

Keep notes, as contacting Apple support is really the best way for this until others can reproduce the issue (and perhaps Apple needs to retest it on older hardware or perhaps even issue a fix in an update).

Comment: This is an example of a good / proper response.